# Chrome extension: Open html in the crx file with no icon on tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am developing a simple chrome extension which substitutes the current default new tab page by opening an index.html in the extension's .crx directory.

Currently the new tab page has already been modified with new index.html page, however, there is no icon on the tab.

May I ask why? Thanks so much!

**Current Problem that the new tab page opened with no icon on the tab**

[Current Problem](http://7u2mbg.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/Snip20150422_60.png)

**The extension directory looks like this：**

[directory](http://7u2mbg.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/Snip20150419_12.png)

**code of manifest.json is as follows**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,  
    "name": "千山",  
    "version": "0.1.0",  
    "description": "测试", 
    "icons": {"16": "icon200.png", "48": "icon200.png", "128": "icon200.png"},
    "browser_action": {  
        "default_icon": "icon.png" ,
        "default_title": "测试",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "index.html"
    }
}
```

**head of index.html is as follows and I wrote  actually but it did not show up**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-cn">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>千山</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="fav.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the relative path "fav.ico" with the full extension path of the file. In JavaScript you can get the full path by calling `chrome.runtime.getURL("fav.ico")`.

If you know the full path and take precautions to make sure the ID of your extension does not change over time (by always publishing using the same `key.pem` file), then hard-coding the path will work and won't require any JavaScript.

You *may* also need to add "fav.ico" to the `web_accessible_resources` part of your `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "fav.ico",
        "bootstrap.min.css"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not a "default" icon - there is no icon *at all*. Same with the default Chrome New tab page.

I suspect this is intentional, to differentiate the New tab page from others.

So, while this is not documented, I assume that there is no way to show the icon.